# Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.0.1)

Tags: android, maven, unity-game-engine, gradle, jcenter

I have a unity project I am exporting that project as android studio project while opening the android studio project I am getting this error

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find manifest-merger.jar
    (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.0.1).
    Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.0.1/manifest-merger-26.0.1.jar
```

I have a few old exported project that was working fine before but today they are also giving the same error.

Comment: check if you have two activities with same name in the manifest

Comment: Nope there's only one activity that is UnityPlayerActivity

Comment: does that have intent filter "android.intent.action.MAIN" and "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" ??

Comment: yep it has the intent filter

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue. This may be a workaround but it works.
So if anyone having this issue, just follow this:

1. Swap the position of `jcenter()` and `google()` in project gradle file and in also all the other module you have in your project. Like in mine I have `crashlytics`, `fabric` so just remember to make the changes in their `build.gradle` file as well:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
           google()
       }
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Before building your project again go to your project folder and delete the `.gradle` folder from your project and then build your project.

Answer (score 16):

1. Go to Publishing Settings/Build, enable Custom Gradle Template
2. Go to Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle and change the postion from

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
}
```

to

```
 buildscript {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
}
```

3. Remove gradle cache and rebuild. For Mac you can run rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/ in terminal.

Comment: thanks! saved my day. it worked after removing cache, rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. So happy to hear that.  @Deepaksharma

Answer (score 0):

Jcenter no longer hosts google dependencies, these can be resolved from "https://maven.google.com"
so you can simply add that to the resolvers list along with jcenter.

Regards,
Itamar

Comment: you mean adding  
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'         }   this into repositories right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely having `jcenter()` above `google()`.
However for me, my `build.gradle` was correct.
The problem happened because of one of my dependencies library had that problem.
The problem seemingly started happening out of nowhere, probably because my jar was cached.

I solved the problem by upgrading my problematic library to latest version as that contained a fix.